# Is the Product of Banach Spaces a Banach Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, direct-sum

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces (not necessarily possessing the same norm). The product space $X×Y=Z$ is given the max norm, i.e. $\max(\Vert x\Vert, \Vert y\Vert)$, where $x$ is given the norm of $X$ and $y$ is given the norm of $Y$, and where $(x,y)$ is an element of $Z$. Prove that the product space $Z$ is Banach.

Comment: Hint: what does it mean that some $(x_n)\in X\times Y$ is a cauchy sequence?

Answer (score 1):

$z_n=(x_n,y_n)$ is a cauchy (convergent) sequence in $Z$ iff $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ both are cauchy (convergent).

Comment: Sorry for replying so tardily, but am I correct in saying that as xn is a convergent sequence as X is complete and yn is a convergent sequence as Y is complete, then the max(||zn||,||zm||) tends to zero and thus Z is also complete?

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in your comment. What is "max(||zn||,||zm||)tends to zero"?

Comment: I am new to this so apologies. I am viewing this as the distance (metric induced by the given norm) between two Cauchy sequences in Z. I believe the distance between them should converge to zero as n, m tend to infinity. Am I on the right track, or have I missed something rather basic?

Comment: Yes you are correct.Basically to show $Z$ is complete you have to start with a cauchy sequence $z_n$ and show that it is convergent.

Comment: Thanks alphad - much obliged.